# "error: expected class-name before '{' token" trying to inheritance

Tags: c++, list, templates

I tried to create a queue that inherits from list and get this error:

```
"error: expected class-name before '{' token"
```

these are the codes that I have ...

**cola_lista.cpp**

```
#ifndef cola_hereda_lista
#define cola_hereda_lista

#include <iostream>
#include "lista_t.hpp"
//#include "nodo_t.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <class T>

class cola : public lista{
    private:
        nodo<T> *frente, *final;
    public:
        cola();
        bool es_vacia();
        int longitud(); //  
        void encolar(T e);
        void desencolar(); //precondicion ¬es_vacia
        T obtener_frente(); //precondicion ¬es_vacia
        ~cola();    
};

#endif
```

**lista.hpp**

```
#ifndef lista_template
#define lista_template

#include <iostream>
#include "nodo_t.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <class T>

class lista{
    private:
        nodo<T> *primero, *ultimo;
        int cantidad;
    public:
//
};
```

**nodo.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef nodo_template
#define nodo_template

using namespace std;

template <class T>

class nodo{
    private:

        T elemento;
        nodo<T> *siguiente;

    public:

        nodo();
        T get_elem();
        void set_elem(T e);
        nodo<T>* get_siguiente();
        void set_siguiente(nodo<T> *sigui);
        ~nodo();
};
```

I've been hours trying to figure out what is what is ill-posed in the code. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your declaration of `cola`:

```
template <class T>
class cola : public lista<T>
                         ^^^
```

`cola` is a class template and you need to specify the type. Also you should not put `using namespace std;` in your header files and I would discourage you from using it in general, this previous thread [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) goes into why.

Comment: Yes, now if compiles fine. Thank you!

I have commented # include nodo.hpp That's good, right? Since lista.hpp Previously included.

Comment: @Geekne reduces unnecessary includes is good but if you have proper include guards which it looks like you do then it should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to this

```
template <class T>
class cola : public lista<T>{
```

Comment: It worked! I'm sure I had tried that before. I guess I must have something wrong. Thank you.

Now, a little doubt ... ...

In **cola_lista.cpp** I have commented # include nodo.hpp That's good, right? Since **lista.hpp** previously included.